# Select rows with JOIN using a subquery

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Hey I have a problem getting the proper info from my database with the queries that I use, I have the following database:

Deck

```
PK - ID  - int
Deckname - varchar(255)
```

Card

```
PK - ID      - int
PK Cardname  - varchar(255)
Cardvalue    - int
Amount       - int
```

Now when I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Card WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Card WHERE Cardname = 'pickachu');
```

Where the Card table has the following values:

```
1    pickachu     50      1
1    charmender   55      2
2    squirtle     65      2
```

I get these rows back:

```
1    pickachu     50      1
1    charmender   55      2
```

ID = 1 because pickachu has id 1, I use that to get all the cards that have ID 1.

Now in adition, I want the deckname aswell (ID 1 in the card table relates to the ID 1 in the deck).

So lets assume we have the following values in Deck:

```
1    myFirstDeck
2    mySecondDeck
```

I now want to get this in return:

```
1    pickachu     50      1    myFirstDeck
1    charmender   55      2    myFirstDeck
```

I have been trying to get this using the following query:

```
SELECT Card.*, Deck.Deckname FROM Card INNER JOIN Deck ON (Card.ID = Deck.ID) WHERE Card.Cardname = 'pickachu';
```

But this only returns pickachu to me, and not charmender which I want aswell. How can I adjust this query to get the desired results?

Comment: Well, your clause says you want only those where Cardname is pikachu, so of course you only get those. Also why do both tables have ID columns that are linked to each other? ID is usually unique, it should be deck_id for example if it links to deck table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sub-query` can't be removed.

```
SELECT c.*, d.Deckname
FROM Card as c INNER JOIN Deck as d ON c.ID = d.ID
WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Card WHERE Cardname = 'pickachu');
```